# How to return queryset instead of list from Django model manager with custom SQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm dealing with a legacy data source and a driver not supported by Django orm.  I can only submit queries using their proprietary odbc driver via pyodbc.  My workaround is to submit custom sql via pyodbc from the model manager.  This techniqe (inspired by Django documentation) returns a list and not a queryset.  This works great until I use packages that expect querysets.

How do I convert the result list to a queryset?  Is there a way to inject the results into a queryset?

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def getdata(self):
        con_string = 'DSN=myOdbcDsn;UID=id;PWD=pass'
        conn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        result_list = []
        try:
            sql = "select distinct coalesce(WORKCENTER_GROUP, 'na') workcenterGroup, WORKCENTER_CODE workcenterCode FROM Workcenter"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                p = self.model(workcenterGroup=row[0], workcenterCode=row[1])
                result_list.append(p)
        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            print("----------------ERROR %s: %s" % (ex.args[0], ex.args[1]))
        conn.close()
        return result_list

class ProdTrends2(models.Model):
    workcenterGroup=models.CharField("Group", max_length=100)
    workcenterCode=models.CharField("Code", max_length=100)
    objects=MyManager()
```

Comment: Can you please share the model codes?

Comment: Updated with model

Answer (score 0):

Calling `set(result_list)` should be enough to satisfy packages the need a Queryset.

Comment: This still throws errors because "set" type doesn't have all the methods and properties of a queryset.